# onTouchBegan not working cocos2dx

Tags: c++, events, cocos2d-x

try to play around with cocos2dx with cpp:

Here is the Header file:

```
#ifndef FirstScene_h
#define FirstScene_h

#include "cocos2d.h"
class FirstScene: public cocos2d::Scene
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();
    void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
    CREATE_FUNC(FirstScene);

    bool onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event);
    bool onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event * event);
    bool onTouchEnd(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event);

private:
    cocos2d::Label *logLabel;  
};
#endif /* FirstScene_h */
```

And here is the cpp file:

```
#include "FirstScene.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

USING_NS_CC;
Scene* FirstScene::createScene(){
    return FirstScene::create();
}

bool FirstScene::init(){
    if(!Scene::init()){
        return false;
    }

    auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto label = Label::createWithTTF("this is the first scene", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);
    label->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2);

    this->addChild(label,1);

    auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");
    sprite->setPosition(visibleSize.width/3,visibleSize.height/3);

    logLabel = Label::createWithTTF("Log holder", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);

    logLabel->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2 + 10.0f, visibleSize.height/2 + 10.0f);
    this->addChild(logLabel,3);

    this->addChild(sprite,0);

    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(FirstScene::onTouchBegan, this);
    listener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(FirstScene::onTouchMoved, this);
    listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(FirstScene::onTouchEnd, this);

    return true;
}

bool FirstScene::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event) {
    CCLOG("touch at x=%f, y=%f", touch->getLocation().x, touch->getLocation().y);
    std::string s = "";
    s += "touch at x=";
    s += touch->getLocation().x;
    s += "y=";
    s += touch->getLocation().y;
    logLabel->setString(s);
    return true;
}

bool FirstScene::onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event) {

    std::string s = "";
    s += "touch moved at x=";
    s += touch->getDelta().x;
    s += " y=";
    s += touch->getDelta().y;
    CCLOG("touch moved at x=%f, y=%f", touch->getDelta().x, touch->getDelta().y);
    logLabel->setString(s);
    return true;
}

bool FirstScene::onTouchEnd(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event) {
    std::string s="";
    s += "touch ended at x=";
    s += touch->getLocation().x;
    s += " y=";
    s += touch->getLocation().y;


    CCLOG("touch ended at x=%f, y=%f", touch->getLocation().x, touch->getLocation().y);
    logLabel->setString(s);
    return true;
}
```

The things I want is when I touch and move on the screen, the log will be showed and the `logLabel` will show the message, but it seems there is no message saw either in the log window nor the logLabel changed.

What did I missing?

### Note

I load this scene by one previous scene by following code if it matters:

```
void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{ 
    auto firstScene = FirstScene::createScene();
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(firstScene);
}
```

Really a newbie for cocos2dx and cpp, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add/register you event listener to event dispatcher :

```
Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```

- If you want to add an event listener for a specified event with the priority of scene graph :

  ```
  addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(EventListener* listener, Node* node)
  ```
- else want add an event listener for a specified event with the fixed priority.

  ```
  addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(EventListener* listener, Node* node)
  ```